# Android - Change the name of app and select the main layout

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I try to change app_name to "LangMe" but it show "Pram" instead..
I want main layout Pram.java but it show NewPost.java

Any suggestion, Thanks for your help in advanced

this is AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.parse.starter"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<permission
    android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.parse.starter.ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.starter.Pram"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pram" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_sign_up" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.starter.Dash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dash" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.starter.NewPost"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_post" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.starter.BrowserByLang"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_browser_by_lang" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.starter.Post"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_post" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

strings.xml file :`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">LangMe</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hey there Please Sign up!</string>
<string name="register">Sign up</string>
<string name="userNameSignUp">Username</string>
<string name="RePasswordSignUp">pass</string>
<string name="EmailSignUp">Email</string>
<string name="PasswordSignUp">pass</string>
<string name="title_activity_pram">Login </string>
<string name="signin">Please Sign in:</string>
<string name="username">Username:</string>
<string name="password">Password:</string>
<string name="signInButton">Sign in</string>
<string name="email">Email address:</string>
<string name="title_activity_dash">Dashboard</string>
<string name="newEntry">Post new entry</string>
<string name="correctSomeEntries">Correct others posts</string>
<string name="browserYourEntries">Browse your posts</string>
<string name="title_activity_new_post">Publish new post</string>
<string name="publish">Publish</string>

<string-array name="langs">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>German</item>
    <item>Polish</item>
    <item>Arabic</item>
    <item>French</item>
</string-array>

<string name="title_activity_browser_by_lang">Last Enties</string>
<string name="title_activity_post">LangMe</string>
<string name="comments">Comments</string>
<string name="addComment">Add comment</string>
<string name="signOut">Sign out</string>
<string name="title_sign_up">New user</string>
```

any solution?

Comment: it is not very clear what your problem is/what you are trying to do

Comment: android keep my app name as previous one.

Comment: I don't see any `app_name` or `LangMe` in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Open your **strings.xml** file from **res**-->**values** folder then replace...

```
<string name="app_name">Pram</string>
```

with...

```
<string name="app_name">LangMe</string>
```

Comment: No my question is when I build the app and run it I get the previous name of my app "Pram" but I want to name it "langMe"

Comment: see the updated answer...may be this is what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I seen it. Its absolutely correct. Last option in my for which your application may change is...in your activity, you may write **setTitle("Pram");** which change the app name. check this carefully.

Comment: unfortunetly there is no such line like this in all of my activities!

Comment: Now, I can't find out any more cause.

Comment: that's why I ask here for the second time in my life :D

Comment: yes. I made clear then build for the project, which solve the problem automatecly

Answer (score 0):

In res folder you will find the strings.xml file. In there you will have
Pram So change Pram to LangMe. save the file and build again for the name change to take effect